# Trying to create CSV file, keep getting TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a CSV file.  I type the code into pythons IDLE python version 3.4.3 and get the following
(I dont understand why i get TypeError: 'str', there is no str type in my coe)

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow([3,4])
    spamwriter.writerow([6,7])



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 4, in <module>
    spamwriter.writerow([3,4])
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `wt` as the file mode, not `wb`. `wb` opens the file in binary mode, when the csv module expects a file opened in text mode.

Also, if you're on Windows, you're going to want to open the file with `open('eggs.csv', 'wt', newline='')` otherwise you'll end up with an additional blank line between each row.